# GWT MVP Pattern (Guice-Dispatcher) Performace Problem

Tags: gwt, guice, dispatcher, gwt-mvp

I am using MVP pattern in my GWT project (Guice and Dispatch and..)

But each RPC to the server after 30 sec after last RPC take a delay(about 1 sec).
IT seems something is being cached in the server for 30sec and guess it is for Guice runtime injection or Dispatcher.

How to kill this delay?

Answer (score 1):

Use a profiler to see where the time is actually spent, the JDK comes with VisualVM which I would try first.

Guice injection might take a little time to analyze the class and dependency structure, but that work is only done when you call Injector.inject(...) which you should only call when the servlet is initialized.

Comment: I put it in web-listener so it run first in deployment

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't initialize the Guice injector for every request, the injector should be built once and stored.

Comment: I put it in web-listener so it run first at deployment time